# How to Login with only Mobile number in aws for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I have used AWS userpool for signup/Login for users.

First user will signup with mobile number,name and email.
User will get confirmation code on mobile and if he verify it will successfully register in app.

After Logout from APP.

Now if user wants to login in app he need to enter only mobile number and he receive OTP and by verifying OTP he will logged in.

But How to send OTP to Confirmed status user for Login ??